# IOS6.0, SupportedInterfaceOrientations in Navigation base application

Tags: ios

I have a navigation base application which was moved from Xcode 3.2 to 4.6 recently.

As the ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS 6 and I used that to force a particular views to  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft only, and the others to UIDeviceOrientationPortrait only, so I add the fellowing code to corresponding ViewController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotate");
        return YES;
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotate");
        return YES;
}
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    NSLog(@"UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft");
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Then the ViewController pushed into the navigation only log "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait", and the view rotate when the device rotate. (this is not what I want)
the ViewController show up by [self presentModalViewController:] can log both "shouldAutorotate" and "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft", and doesn't rotate when the device rotate.(this is what I want)

How can I make the view pushed into the navigation working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `UINavigationcontroller` in your application and you need to have different interface orientations then it could mess up the interface orientation in the application, solution is to  implement a custom `UINavigationController` and implement the interface orientation methods within that custom `UINavigationController` class, this will make your viewControllers rotate according to the orientation you set because your controllers are pushed from the `UINavigationController`.

for pushing the viewController on `UINavigationController` you should do like this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

I had the similar problem when using navigationController, my views were not rotating properly so i implemented the custom `navigationController` like this

**CustomNavigationController.h**

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController
@end
```

**CustomNavigationController.m**

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

//overriding shouldRotate method for working in navController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{  
  return   [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];   
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your appDelegate Method:

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

Hope this will help you.

All the best !!!